# Is there an easy way to convert excel forumla into android app?

Tags: android, excel, formula

I am very new to android but I have searched about half the day for answers, or even thoughts on converting excel formulas to android.  I'm not looking for a converter, just a process where I can get the same results in android.  Please forgive me for lack of knowledge, I want to learn and hoping I can get this done.

My excel formula is very basic, it calculates the answer using the values of 4 cells which values are dependent on user input.  Two of the cells are static drop-down lists, two are user-input numeric.  I have a database of figures relating to the two drop-down lists, it is a bunch of IF statements, for example, IF,(A2="Pizza",C2). Where C2= the predetermined value of Pizza in the database.

My thoughts were that I could put the four boxes on the app, then the action button would match the two spinners to their database values, send them and the two numeric values to through the formula and the answer would be output.

Does that make sense?  Is it possible?  Can someone put me on the right path so I can research more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program is simple enough, you may be able to use something like [App Inventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/). It has limited features but it's designed for people who have no high level programming experience.

If that doesn't do the trick, you're a long way from being able to accomplish your stated goal. First thing you'll need to do is [learn the basics of Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) (which is the lingua franca of Android). Once you're able to translate your 'excel' logic into Java, you can [start putting together an Android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) application. Vogella also has some [pretty good tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html).

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you.  I do not mind putting in months of work to get to where I want to be, I just wanted to know which path to start out on.